# my computer lags when playing 3d games (Nvidia GeForce 4 MX420)

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, games, 3d

Hello when i try to play 3d games on my computer like tux racer and other games it lags really bad. When i look in additional drivers it doesn't detect new drivers for my machine.
I'm running lubuntu 14.04 and my graphics card is Nividia Mx 420 my proccessor is a AMD Athlon xp + 2000 1.66 ghz. SO why is my computer lagging?. Thank you for reading this

Comment: Open software centre, click edit and software sources, click aditional drivers tab and post a screenshot of that (Alt+Print Screen) on http://imgur.com and give us the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What driver for nVIDIA GeForce MX440?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210493/what-driver-for-nvidia-geforce-mx440)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: wow, that's 12 year old hardware.

Then again, Tux Racer is non-demanding and pre-dates your hardware, so it should in theory work fine.

Support for your GPU is not baked in to current-generation nVidia proprietary drivers.

For your graphics card you'll need to obtain a legacy driver from the 96.43.xx series.

This driver *was* available in some versions of Ubuntu's restricted archive, but doesn't seem to be included anymore (unless it's been renamed?).  You'll probably need to go the route of installing it yourself from nVidia's website:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

Installation mainly consists of executing the downloaded file to build the driver, then running `nvidia-xconfig` to set up X to use the driver.  You may find you need dependencies in order to install the driver, but it should let you know about them.

Comment: how do i install the driver because when i downloaded it and open it it launch in leafpad text editor.

Comment: You need to execute it, not open it in a text editor.  There are further installation instructions in the link provided.  Direct link to readme: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/96.43.23/README/README.txt